# How to check, if my ASUS Nexus 7 LTE really is LTE version?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, 4g

Following [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/62274/20449) and my many further tests, I begin to fear, that my ASUS Nexus 7 II (2013) LTE isn't actually a LTE version and I simply has been cheated, paying for LTE version and getting 3G one.

What is the best way to check / prove, that this device really is LTE version?

Does the facts:

- phone detects network as `LTE` (though is unable to connect to it),
- after upgrading system to `4.4.2 KitKat` I have [access to new option](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62637/20449) `Settings > Wireless & networks > More > Mobile Networks > Preferred network` and I can select `4G` there.

are enough to be sure, that this is really an LTE-based version of ASUS Nexus 7 tablet?

My doubts come from three facts:

1. When I insert a LTE-compatible SIM card, tablet is able to detect, that it is in LTE signal range, but is unable to login to LTE network and obtain an IP address. The very same card inserted into another LTE device (some Samsung phablet) logins to LTE network at once and works like a charm.
2. Working Samsung was checked at provider's office and provider's representative did check APN. Beside, SIM cards used by this provider are somehow self-configurable. Once inserted, they set APNs by themselves and select the proper one.
3. I've checked and verified, that my network carrier (Polish Plus GSM) is using LTE on the 1800 MHz band, which is [confirmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013_version)#Model_variants) to be all fine with ASUS Nexus 7 II (2013) LTE tablet.

Are there any other things, that I can check to make myself sure, that I really have LTE model?

Comment: Just a raw idea: Have you compared the APN config of the (working) Sammy against those of the (not working) N7? Maybe your provider uses/requires different settings for 4G.

Comment: Working Samsung was checked at provider's office and provider's representative did check APN. Beside, SIM cards used by this provider are somehow self-configurable. Once inserted, they set APNs by itself at selects proper one.

Comment: I've integrated that fact with your question. As APN selection can only be done by the Android system (based on information from the inserted SIM; I know this as a fact from e.g. CyanogenMod), and the ROMs of both devices certainly differ, I suggest a manual (visual) comparision nevertheless. It could very well be the database of your N7 is somehow "incorrect", and thus wrong APN data might get set up.

Comment: Your comment enforced me for a little bit deeper search and it seems, that you're right. I found some pages about detailed APN settings for this provider. I'll try to use them this day evening or next one (once I get back Nexus to my hands) and eventually report results here. Thanks!

Comment: I will wait for your details then to convert my comments to an "enriched answer". Good luck until then!

Comment: Hi Izzy. Turned out, you were right and carrier's customer support was wrong. SIM cards for this carrier (Plus GSM, Poland) are self-configurable, but only for up to 3G network. LTE network, since is still being a rather new / tested solution, requires special APN settings. Once entered manually, LTE on my Nexus 7 started to work immediately and I got godspeeds of around 27 MB/s download. Please, convert key points from your comments to full answer, so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Glad we were able to solve the issue, and you now have a fully operable N7 :)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine! :> Have a nice weekend and thanks! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by a wrong APN configuration. Though customer care told you their card is "self configurable", this may well be relative: many ROMs (especially custom ROMs like [cyanogenmod](/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod)) come with a built-in list of APNs, which are matched against the provider as specified by the SIM card, and used correspondingly.

While those matches usually are fine, there might be exceptions – e.g. when the provider made changes to his configuration after the ROM was released. Or did not provide all details: APNs might need different parameters for e.g. 3G than for LTE. As you've got a second Android device where the card is working fine,

- put the SIM into that device
- go to *Settings* (usually network → telephony or similarly; different ROMs might place it slightly different)
- tap the APN and select to adjust it
- do not adjust anything, just write down its parameters

In a second step,

- put the same SIM to your N7
- go to the same *Settings* page
- compare your values and, if something differs, adjust it

I bet your device then will connect fine. If not (or if there are no differences), it's probably a hardware issue, and you need to send your N7 for service.